Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription’s customize message content per subscription
I have multiple subscriptions for the service bus topic.  I want to send a short form of a message to per subscribers. e.g. in the topic, a json message is being posted with properties A, B , C, D. I want sub1 receive a full message, however, Sub2 can only see part of the message that is A.B and Sub3 can see A,B,C. In short I want to send a custom form of message to each subscriber.  I am not looking to use the filter, as I understood filter only filter out the entire message either to pass to subscriber or not
I tried to use filter but filter does not serve the purpose what I am looking

Azure Service Bus cannot modify the body of the message. Only headers can mutated. And event then, I'd say this is undesirable. If you're trying to limit what each subscriber can see, you should probably publish different events.

There is no facility to do this directly in Azure Service Bus. You would need to do this at the application level e.g. by deploying an Azure function that reads the messages from a queue, mutates them as desired, and forwards them to different topics for each version of the message contents needed.
